# Adding an empty line in a paragrapgh using python/nltk

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, nltk

In the below string I want to replace \xa0 with an empty line:

Example sentence 1\xa0 Example sentence 2\xa0 Example Sentence 3\xa0 Example Sentence 4\xa0\

So, the output should be:

Example sentence 1

Example sentence 2

Example Sentence 3

Example Sentence 4

My code is:
A[0].replace('\xa0','\n\n')

but it is not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?

Comment: also:  `\x` escape sequence means the next two characters are interpreted as hex digits for the character code, so **this is not a valid python string**.